# Building up an online administration service, what database strategy should I go for

Tags: mysql, sql, database, structure

I'm building up an online (paid) service used for business administration purposes. The database is structured like so:

I have a contacts table filled with persons, contact info and the like. Then I have a few other tables holding information about payments, agreements and appointments. Also statistics like how much money was transferred this month, how many hours worth of appointments this month and the like.

I'm using MySQL (but could also go for MSSQL or some other service if necessary) and I had no formal training in any programming language whatsoever (yet).

I'm building a WPF application for acces to this database. Also planning on building an app so users can access their data and plan new appointments and register payments on the go.
I'm going to go for a login system to verify their right to login and use my service.

My question is about how to structure this. I'm not an SQL expert nor have I had any formal training in SQL or any other programming language. What I do know though is that my client-side app is almost out of the alpha stage.

So far I have come up with two ways to structure this.

**1. Users get a seperate database.**

My original idea was to give each user a seperate database, this makes it easier to provide people with statistics. Also it makes it easier to spread the workload through multiple, seperate servers. People would login to a master/main server, where their login information is stored, fetch their server info and programatically be 'redirected' to their own database. Spreading these databases also make it easier to provide individual back-ups to users.

The down-side of this is the sheer quantity of databases I'd have to manage. I'm planning on ending up with hundreds of thousands of users. Let's just say I want the system to be able to provide to an infinite amount of users.

**2. Everything is stored in one database.**

It's also possible to store everything in one database. This would make the database structure somewhat more complicated (while it also makes the whole a lot simpler). I'd have to add 'AND consumer_ID='" + MyID + "' to every query. (Which ofcourse is possible) and add a few tables to handle statistics per user.

It would be simpler to provide every user with the same database updates. Maintenance would be easier.

The down-side of this is that it makes it harder to spread the workload to seperate servers, I'd have to build something to make it possible that seperate servers mirror each other. Also I'd have to make sure that the workload is automatically divided between the servers, instead of simply going for: Fill server with X databases, then new server, fill, new etc.

I'm not in the luxury of hiring someone with any SQL training.

The most important thing for me now is that the system can be easily maintained while still being safe and reliable. I'm an amateur developer, going to college next year. I don't want to spend 50% of my time maintaining the database.

I think I got the major part of the details you might need, if you need anymore please ask for them.
I thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with solution 2. The downside of spreading the workload to many servers is fullfilled by "partitioning", look here for a starting point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

Partitioning would allow you for example to put all information of a table containing even IDs for consumers on the one, all other on the second server. Or whatever you want...

But i wouldn't start that complicated: do you need that now? It burdens you (either way) with such a big additional overhead! You can also look into the NoSQL database world for solutions that can be spread to as many servers as you want with low effort. You loose SQL and it's ACID features in the most cases; if you need those NoSQL is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do need those SQL features. I do know how to manage and build a relatively efficient database. I've had some experience with databases, just not with the size I want to have now. I think I'll stick with solution nr.2 for now, unless anyone disagrees with good arguments, this indeed is easier. I know there is a whole lot possible with databases, I just need to know the right features. Before/while 'expanding' further I'm going to do a lot of reading :) Any ideas on which SQL provider I should use (MySQL, MSSQL /// anything I haven't heard of)?

Comment: I have only worked with MySQL so far, but PostgreSQL looks more promising to me. It is more consistent (only ONE table-type for example) and has nice features that i miss with MySQL (for example DDL statements are handled within transactions). Unfortunately i have no clue of commercial database products.

Comment: It seems that PostgresSQL is not widely supported. A google search for hosting in my country turned up zero results. Mainly more questions like: "I want PostgresSQL hosting but can't find it!" I will try to install PostgresSQL on my machine in the near future so I can compare the versions.

Comment: Oh, my comparison was not even an attempt to be complete; i have very good experiences with MySQL, but the main things that i don't like with MySQL are all not existent with PostgreSQL. However, there may be other things that are bad with PostgreSQL, i just don't know of any (other than support, which is no argument in my case because i use a dedicated server for internal purposes with MySQL)